# Ghost images coronado telescope

Tags: the-sun

I have just purchased a Coronado Solarmax III 70mm. To make it clear I am not an astronomer or an astrographer. I just need the telescope for an art installation purpose. I am having trouble with multiple ghost images of the sun. Any suggestions what might be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe the ghost images.  It's common to see reflections when the Sun is out of the field of view.  But when the sun is in the field of view, it overwhelms any reflections.